# Visual studio Access DB insert id thats bigger as previous id

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

#### Good day reader,

i have a question about vb access insert, I have an id, but I what the next insert id to automatically get a higher number. this is the code I have so far:

Try

```
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\data\testing.Accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
        cn.Open()


        Dim sSQL As String = "insert into tabel1(id) values(@d1)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, cn)

        Dim id As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d1", OleDbType.VarWChar, 25)
        id.Value = 'so here I need the automatic higher number
        cmd.Parameters.Add(id)
```

I really hope one of you guys can help me with this, thanks already.
sorry for my bad English it because I’m Dutch, if have any question I’ll try to explain it.

regards Tom

Comment: You need an AutoIncrement flag for your ID field. Then the insertion of the new number is done automatically by the database engine

Comment: any i idea how i can do that in code, my db is add to project by code. because i dont really uderstand what you mean. but thanks already for your fast reaction.

Comment: When you say "my db is add to project by code" do you mean that you are creating the table from within your VB.NET code, perhaps by running a DDL command like `CREATE TABLE table1 ...`?

Comment: no my db is made in access and added to vb datagridvieuw by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a nested sub query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Id,Test) SELECT TOP 1 MAX(ID) + 1,"Test Value" FROM Table1;
```

In this example I added another field called "Test" so you can see how you would enter values for the other fields.

Comment: BTW, The "TOP 1" is not required because the MAX() will only return 1 record but it is good habit to prevent you from grabbing something else from the same table and then causing errors.